# Prove $\frac{\tan\theta}{1-\cot\theta}+\frac{\cot\theta}{1-\tan\theta}=\sec \theta\csc\theta+1$

Tags: trigonometry

I did it by converting every trigonometry stuff into ${\sin}$ and $\cos$. But I want to know if there is a shortcut (without converting everything to $\sin$ and $\cos$) to do this. Please help.

Comment: Use two $ signs to enclose your formulas...

Comment: Try break all terms in form of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{\cot\theta}=\tan\theta=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{\sec\theta}{\csc\theta}$$

$$\dfrac{\tan\theta}{1-\cot\theta}=\dfrac{\sec^2\theta}{\csc\theta(\sec\theta-\csc\theta)}$$

Similarly, $$\dfrac{\cot\theta}{1-\tan\theta}=?$$

---

Alternatively,

$$\dfrac{\tan\theta}{1-\cot\theta}=\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}$$

Similarly, $$\dfrac{\cot\theta}{1-\tan\theta}=?$$

Comment: I got the other part as $\frac{\csc^2\theta}{\sec\theta(\csc\theta-\sec\theta)}$ so what then ?

Comment: @Nimantha, Now the two terms & simplify. You can use either of the methods

Comment: I don't see way to prove what is in the question.Please help.

Comment: @Nimantha, $$\dfrac{a^2}{b(a-b)}+\dfrac{b^2}{a(a-b)}=\dfrac{a^3-b^3}{ab(a-b)}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+ab}{ab}=\dfrac{a^2b^2+ab}{ab}=?$$ as $a^2+b^2=\cdots=a^2b^2$

Comment: @Nimantha, please try with sine, cosine : that's much easier to deal with

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee Thanks for your help.